# How do you prove that (A,B) = trace(AB) is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

This is a bilinear form on nxn matrices.  Is it positive definite?

Comment: Property 3 follows from the general fact that the trace is additive: $tr(A + B) = tr(A) + tr(B)$.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps. You mention property numbers that make no sense without a reference. Perhaps you could start by listing the properties in your question.

Comment: $$ \operatorname{tr}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}^2\right)=\operatorname{tr}\left(\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right)=-2 $$

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly *not* the case that $Tr(A^2)\ge 0$ for all $A$.  For example, if $A$ is the 2x2 matrix giving a 90 degree rotation of the plane, then $Tr(A^2)$ is $-2$.  Perhaps you want to define $(A,B)=Tr(A^{T}B)$ instead?  That makes $(A,A)\ge 0$ easy to show (for $A$ real) since it's just the sum of the squares of the entries of $A$.  For $A$ complex, use the conjugate transpose instead of the ordinary transpose, and you will be fine then, too.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It should probably be a comment, or you might go on to prove that $\operatorname{tr}\left(A^TA\right)\gt0$ if $A\ne0$.

Comment: I did, and more (handling $A$ complex also).  Anyway, it was pretty cheap of you to copy my answer into your comment.

Comment: I was writing that comment before your answer was posted. Sorry you think it was cheap; not like I get anything from it.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://sistemas.fciencias.unam.mx/~erhc/algebra_lineal_20181/traza_ortogonalidad.pdf) can help, do it is in Spanish and proved in the complex space.